# Rename model with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I know with normal migrations I could do rename_table but in mongoid I'm not at all sure how to proceed.

I've got all my models/relations/routes/controllers/etc all renamed but I just need to know how to move the data itself.

This is an embedded embeds_one document btw.

UPDATE:

Looks like simply doing:

```
Model.all.each {|m| m.rename :old_embedded_association_name, :new_embedded_association_name }
```

Works.  Sound sane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For renaming embedded docs, you treat them just like you would an attribute and rename them using something like this:

`ParentModel.all.each {|m| m.rename :old_embedded_association_name, :new_embedded_association_name }`

For renaming top level models, you need to access the ruby driver itself and use the #rename_collection method:

`Mongoid.database.rename_collection "old_collection_name", "new_collection_name"`

To see the old collection name you can do something like this:

`Mongoid.database.collections.map {|c| c.name}`

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `database' for Mongoid:Module

Comment: The command in more recent versions is: Mongoid.default_client.collections.map {|c| c.name}

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to rename a collection. I like to do it via Moped (https://github.com/mongoid/moped/blob/master/lib/moped/collection.rb#L55).

`Mongoid.default_session[:old_name].rename(:new_name)`

This is also a handy for finding the collection name.

`OldModel.collection.name`

Comment: I'm getting NoMethodError: undefined method `default_session' for Mongoid:Module - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said and the documentation it seems you should do it this way

```
Model.rename(:old_name, :new_name)
```